exceljs filters on header disappears and date is not triggering change in other cells
\hello all.
I have an excel file with two pages, one has the summary of the records page(the second sheet), in the summary sheet there is the J1 cell, manually I can change the date from that cell then a bunch of other cells that depend on it also update accordingly. The second sheet with the records it has a list of logs with dates etc... its headers have filters on it.
When I fill the excel file with the data from database the filters from the headers disappear even if the headers are present and I do not touch them, and in the first sheet even if I update J1 the other cell do not update. If I enter the same date manually it works, I checked also the format is the same. In sheet2 I tried to add also the filters later again through code but still there are no filters.
Here is the code:
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'excelFiles', 'logs.xlsx');
const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
await workbook.xlsx.readFile(filePath);

const sheet1 = workbook.getWorksheet('sum');
const sheet2 = workbook.getWorksheet('RECORDS');

const currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setMonth(month)
currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
const formattedDate = `${currentDate.getMonth() + 1}/${currentDate.getDate()}/${currentDate.getFullYear()}`;

sheet1.getCell('J1').value = formattedDate

const currYear = new Date(currentDate.getUTCFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
const logs = await fetchLogs(currYear);
let lastIndex = 0;
logs.forEach((log, index) => {
    const row = sheet2.getRow(index + 2); // skip headers
    row.getCell(1).value = log.location;
    row.getCell(2).value = parseInt(log.tc_no);
    row.getCell(3).value = parseInt(log.card_number);
    row.getCell(4).value = log.login;
    row.getCell(5).value = log.login_device_id;
    row.getCell(6).value = parseInt(log.per_id);
    row.getCell(7).value = log.name;
    row.getCell(8).value = log.surname;
    row.getCell(9).value = { formula: `DATE(LEFT(D${index + 2},4), MID(D${index + 2},6,2), MID(D${index + 2},9,2))` };

    row.getCell(10).value = { formula: `TIME(MID(D${index + 2},12,2), MID(D${index + 2},15,2), MID(D${index + 2},18,2))` };
    row.getCell(11).value = { formula: `C${index + 2}&"/"&D${index + 2}` };
    lastIndex = index + 3
    row.commit();
});

sheet2.autoFilter = {
    from: "A1",
    to: "K1"
};

// sheet2.commit();

res.setHeader(
    'Content-Disposition',
    'attachment; filename=logs.xlsx'
);
res.setHeader(
    'Content-Type',
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
);


await workbook.xlsx.write(res);

The sheet.commit() function also does not work, it says sheets is not a function.
What am I doing wrong?
How can I fix this?
I am using exceljs version:4.4.0
